# JPA @OneToMany results empty

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying acces a MySQL databese through JPA, but the result is always empty.

```
public class Part {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Owner owner;
    ...
}

public class Owner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private Set<Part> parts;
    ... 
}
```

Whenever I try to get the parts connected to an owner, the resulting Set is empty. After calling eg. size() method, it's still empty.

```
List<Owner> owners = em.createQuery("...", Owner.class).getResultList();

for (Owner o : owners) {
    System.out.print(o + ": ");
    Set<Part> parts = o.getParts();
    parts.size()
}
```

Here the parts Set is always empty. In the database it seems to be connected, but I can't get any results out of it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you determine that it's empty? What happens when you print the size? What happens when you iterate throught the parts and print each of them?

Comment: @JBNizet size() returns 0, System.out.println(parts) prints {[]}

Comment: What is the query? Could you show us example data and tell us what the IDs of the selected owners are?

Comment: @JBNizet the query is "SELECT o FROM owners o". It returns the owners correctly.
The sample DB has:
- two parts (id, owner), both assigned to owner #1.
- one owner (id, name).

Comment: I'm even surprised this query works. It should be "select o from Owner o". Try changing the data to see if it returns your modifications. Make sure you've committed your parts.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm sorry, I made the mistake while writing the comment, the query in the code is what you have written.

Comment: How are you sure there should be entities in the set?  When you add an Owner to a part, do you also add that part to the Owner's set of parts?  You must maintain both sides of a bidirectional relationship to keep the cache insynch with the db as JPA does not do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not adding to both sides of your relationship when creating your objects.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side